# Get Single Digit Id Of Radio Button

Tags: android

I would like to get the id of radio buttons, I am using this code:

```
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
        {
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)rGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
            boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
            if (isChecked)
            {
                radioId = rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                System.out.println("Radio Id: "+rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            }
        }
```

The id is returned in this format:

```
2131165247
```

This was working fine until I added another activity and created additional radio buttons, my app doesn't work properly because now the id has changed:

```
2131230783
```

How can I have an id returned with a single digit such that:

```
radioButtonA = 1
radioButtonB = 2
etc.. instead of that long int id
```

Comment: Why does it make a difference how long the `int` is?

Comment: The ids are automatically generated and are subject to change. If you want to maintain a simple value on a view, use a tag

Comment: you can check if radioId == R.id.radioButtonA

Comment: you can set property of seTag() on radio button and then on clicking use getTag() to check.